# SQL Data conversion & division

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, type-conversion

I'm trying to write an SQL statement that would indicate what kind of commission is being given. I'm stuck on the last part that shows what percentage is given because SQL won't convert a char value to money. 
I'm new to this so my conversion attempt may be entirely bogus.

```
CASE 
   WHEN VehicleSales.CommissionSP1 ='500' then 'Flat'
   WHEN VehicleSales.CommissionSP1 = '0' then 'Not Applicable'
      else Convert(int, VehicleSales.CommissionSP1) / Convert (int, VehicleSales.GrossProfit)
END AS Commission_Type
```

Comment: Part of the issue here will be what is the data type of `Commission_Type` - depending on the case statement part used its either varchar or a numeric. The Commission Type and the Commission Percentage should be thought of as 2 separate fields.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I took your advise and moved the division to the SELECT clause but I'm not getting 'Divide by zero error encountered'. Will I have to code zeros out to continue?

Comment: Why do u need to get `divide by zero` error?

Comment: any suggestions on how to post good data in here? Copy and paste is going to be a disaster

Comment: See my answer for how to post data (and for an answer).

Answer (score 0):

I would cast to a float here in the denominator and put in logic to protect against dividing by zero:

```
CASE 
   WHEN VehicleSales.CommissionSP1 ='500' then 'Flat'
   WHEN VehicleSales.CommissionSP1 = '0' then 'Not Applicable'
      else cast(VehicleSales.CommissionSP1 as int)/ case when cast(VehicleSales.GrossProfit as float)=0 then 1 else cast(VehicleSales.GrossProfit as float) end
END AS Commission_Type
```

Comment: This will still return divide by zero error try this `select  cast('120' as int)/ cast('0' as float)`

Comment: I know OP indicated int but I am pretty sure he does not want integer rounding.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your `case` expression here:

1. You are liable to divide by zero errors.
2. You are trying to return multiple data types within the same `case` expression.

If you absolutely need to return `Flat`, `Not Applicable` or a percentage you are going to need to return the percentage as a `nvarchar`/`varchar` string:

```
case VehicleSales.CommissionSP1
   when '500' then 'Flat'
   when '0' then 'Not Applicable'
   else convert(nvarchar(20),isnull(convert(int,VehicleSales.CommissionSP1)
                                    / nullif(convert(decimal(10,2),VehicleSales.GrossProfit),0)
                                   ,0)
               )
   end as Commission_Type
```

---

I would recommend that you don't return the `Flat` and `Not Applicable` values in the same column as your percentage though.  Personally, I would go for one column that holds the commission type and another that holds the relevant value.  This way, you can summarise in commission type groups without having to worry about `convert`ing your data all the time:

```
select case VehicleSales.CommissionSP1
         when '500' then 'Flat'
         when '0' then 'Not Applicable'
         else 'Percentage'
         end as Commission_Type
      ,case VehicleSales.CommissionSP1
         when '500' then 500    -- I am assuming you actually have some way of knowing what is flat beyond hard coding values here.
         when '0' then 0
         else isnull(convert(int,VehicleSales.CommissionSP1)
                                 / nullif(convert(decimal(10,2),VehicleSales.GrossProfit),0)
                                ,0)
         end as Commission
```

Comment: This seems like a great option but it's not liking the 'select' ahead of the 'case'.

Comment: You magnificent bastard - it's working. I added a *100 to get a better looking percentage.

Comment: Thank you so, Have a great day

Answer (score 0):

It will convert varchar to smallmoney.  Learn to break down the problem.

A column (even a case) can only be one data type.

This does not protect from not a number in the varchar or divide by zero on profit.

```
declare @T table (com varchar(10), profit varchar(10));
insert into @T values ('0', '1000'), ('500', '1000'), ('12', '1000'), ('100', '1000');
select t.*, cast(com as smallmoney) comM, CAST(profit as smallmoney) as profitM 
     , case com when '0'   then 'Flat'
                when '500' then 'Not Applicable'
                else            cast(cast(com as smallmoney) / 
                                     CAST(profit as smallmoney) as varchar(100))
       end as smart
from @T t
```